# swap nodes from a linked list java

Tags: java

I am trying to swap two nodes from given positions from a linked list, I currently have done this but nothing is being swapped and I also have to make sure to print an error if they pick a position that is not on the linked list for example there are 5 nodes so if a position is 6 it should print an error where can I put that message. The method can't be changed from the way it is

```
void swapping(int a, int b){
POI curr1;
POI temp = head;
POI temp1;
int i = 1;
POI temp2;
POI curr2;
while(i < a - 1){
  temp= temp.next;
  i++;
}
temp1 = temp;
curr1 = temp1.next;

while(i < b - 1){
  temp= temp.next;
  i++;
}
temp2 = temp;
curr2 = temp2.next;

temp = curr1.next;
temp2.next = curr1;
curr1.next = curr2.next;
```

Comment: One problem seems to be not resetting i when you traverse to the second node.

Comment: How would I reset it

Answer (score 1):

you should read about "pass by reference" vs "pass by value"
in java, primitives (in your case `int a, int b`) are passed by value - meaning java makes a copy of those values, and once method exits - those values no longer exists.

so technically you can't `void swap (int a, int b)`
you'll need a wrapper for that. (indeed there are boxed primitives e.g - `Integer`, but they also won't work in this case because they are immutable)

you should do something like:

```java
 class IntWrapper {
   int value
 }
 
 void swap(IntWrapper a, IntWrapper b) {
   int temp = a.value;
   a.value = b.value;
   b.value = temp.value;
 }
```

because `IntWrapper` is an `Object` it is passed by reference

Comment: i forgot to specify but I can't change the method how it is so its possible I got help on the first while loop

Comment: you cannot do this in java otherwise